# SQL - Insert Into table based on a counter value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql-insert

I have tabA:

```
________________________
|ID  |EMPLOYEE|CODE    |
|49  |name1   |mobile  |
|393 |name2   |none    | 
|3002|name3   |intranet|
________________________
```

The ID column (tabA) is based on a counter in the below tabB:

```
_________________
|TYPE       |ID  |
|intranet   |3003|
|mobile     |50  | 
|none       |394 |
__________________
```

I want to insert new row in tabA using the ID counter (as it is the next available ID). How do I insert into table based on a counter value?

I am trying this method, which results in trying to insert a duplicate type, instead of the max(ID):

```
 INSERT INTO tabA (ID, EMPLOYEE, CODE)
```

`VALUES ((select max(ID) from tabB where TYPE = 'A'),name4,'intranet');`

I expect to see tabA:

```
________________________
|ID  |EMPLOYEE|CODE    |
|3000|name1   |mobile  |
|3001|name2   |none    | 
|3002|name3   |intranet|
|3003|name4   |intranet|
________________________
```

tabB:

```
_________________
|TYPE       |ID  |
|mobile     |2999|
|none       |3002| 
|intranet   |3004|
__________________
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would suggest the following answer:**

**the @tabA and @tabB I assume is your tabA and tabB above.**

```
declare @tabA table
(
    id integer,
    employee nvarchar(10),
    code nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @tabA values (49, 'name1','mobile');
insert into @tabA values (393, 'name2','none');
insert into @tabA values (3002, 'name3','intranet');

declare @tabB table
(
    type_ nvarchar(10),
    ID integer
)

insert into @tabB values ('intranet',3003);
insert into @tabB values ('mobile',50);
insert into @tabB values ('none', 394);

insert into @tabA
select MAX(b.ID), 'name4','intranet'
from @tabB B
where b.type_ = 'intranet'

declare @max integer

select @max = MAX(ID) from @tabB where type_ = 'intranet'

declare @max_1 integer
set @max_1 = @max + 1

update @tabB
set ID = @max_1
from @tabB B
where type_ = 'intranet'

select * from @tabA

select * from @tabB

----------------------------
what I got from @tabA

49      |name1| mobile
393     |name2| none
3002    |name3| intranet
3003    |name4| intranet

what I got from @tabB

intranet|3004
mobile  |50
none    |394
```

Comment: Thank you, it does what I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO tabA(ID, EMPLOYEE, CODE)  
    select max(ID), 'name4', 'intranet'
    from tabB
    where TYPE = 'A';
```

Comment: We need to add `Group By`

Comment: I think you have a typo, it should be `'name4'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same error as what I attempted. Violation of primary key......cannot insert duplicate key in object 'A'...

Comment: @AlkippeNikephoros, try using `max(ID) + 1`.

Comment: This inserts the wrong ID and doesn't use the counter from tabB (so the tabB ID doesn't not change after the query is run). : I would like to use the counter value, which will cause tabB to increase by 1 as that id is used.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem: (Assuming your ID is incremental)

```
INSERT INTO tabA (ID, EMPLOYEE, CODE)

 VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 ID + 1 FROM tabA ORDER BY ID DESC),'name4', 'intranet')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, ID is not always incremental. There is a checkbox through a system. If the box is ticked then unticked (this causes tabA to delete the row of the employee where had the checkbox).  Then ticked again it will use the counter in tabB and assign the employee to the id it got from tabB. Therefore I need to use the counter from tabB to insert the employee in. - it also results in some very high integer (over 3 million above the ID counter in tabB)

Comment: so you mean, it's the highest ID from table B? is that it?

Comment: your question became confusing. i mean how can you generate an ID in tabB that won't duplicate during an insert if you won't increment continuously

Comment: no. It is a value where type = 'intranet' (code in tabA). Basically tabB is being used to ensure no duplicate IDs are created, but manually inserting and ID by not using the counter can cause duplicate ids.- mobile, none, intranet are three different counters. I need to get the highest intranet ID and use it for the insert, which after the insert the tabB intranet ID should be 3004, as I inserted |3003|name4|intranet.

Comment: I mean - tabA would not be incremental as if you delete a row with ID 3001, it creates a new ID for the user if you want to add them again. tabB is increment continuously, after 1 ID is used from the counter, the counter will increase for next time someone else is inserted.

Comment: so ID in tabB is incremental?

Comment: If ID in tabB is incremental then use this 
VALUES ((SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM tabB ORDER BY ID DESC),'name4', 'intranet')